# How to count the frequency of occurrence of items in list in python?

Tags: python, loops, count

I have a list of countries which were extracted from two columns of an excel file. One of the columns has empty rows. So the list contains names of countries and empty rows.

For example `mylist=["Norway", "Brazil", "Ireland", "Scotland", "nan", "nan", "Canada"]`

How do I iterate through the list and print the frequency of occurrences of each country in the list and also skip the empty files?

I've tried so far:

```
countries=[]
for column in survey ['C1']:
    countries.append(column)

for column in survey['C2']:
    countries.append(column)

c=0
for i in countries:
    c+=1
    print(c)
```

With this code I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-08f5eb58f7cb> in <module>()
      1 c=0
      2 for c in countries:
----> 3     c+=1
      4     print(c)
      5 

TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Comment: Please run the same code. In your wrong code you used `for c in countries`

Answer (score 1):

Try with `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

mylist=["Norway", "Brazil", "Ireland", "Scotland", "nan", "nan", "Canada"]

>>> Counter([i for i in mylist if i!="nan"])
Counter({'Norway': 1, 'Brazil': 1, 'Ireland': 1, 'Scotland': 1, 'Canada': 1})
```

###### Edit:

If your list contains actual `nan` values (i.e. not string "nan"), you can use:

```
>>> Counter([i for i in mylist if not pd.isnull(i)])
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
mylist=["Norway", "Brazil", "Ireland", "Scotland", "nan", "nan", "Canada"]
{con : mylist.count(con) for con in set(mylist) if con != "nan"}
```

Output:

```
{'Norway': 1, 'Brazil': 1, 'Ireland': 1, 'Scotland': 1, 'Canada': 1}
```

Comment: Better use `set` not `list`. 
`{con : mylist.count(con) for con in set(mylist) if con != "nan"}`

Comment: @dimay thanks for your comment i edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

you can try a more native way

```
mylist=["Norway", "Brazil", "Ireland", "Scotland", "nan", "nan", "Canada"]
count = {}

for item in mylist:
    if item != "nan":
        if item in count:
            count[item] += 1
        else:
            count[item] = 1
```